# Starting the ValueAnimator outside the UI Thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am trying to run android.animation.ValueAnimator from a separate thread from the UI thread. As I understand it, ValueAnimator can only be ran from the UI thread. Is there a proper way to start it from another thread to run on the UIThread?

I wrapped the ValueAnimator in an other class which holds a switch for the UI thread to periodically check.

```
private ArrayList<Animation> animators;
public void onResume(){
while(true)
        {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            checkAnimations();

        }
}
public void checkAnimations()
    {
        for(Animation va: animators)
        {
            if(va.animationHasStarted())
                va.actuallyStartTheAnimation();
        }
    }
public void RegisterAnimation(Animation valueAnimator)
    {
        animators.add(valueAnimator);
    }
```

The infinite loop causes the UI to stall. Do you know of a better implementation/design pattern.

Comment: If you have an Activity reference, you can call `runOnUiThread()`.

Comment: **ValueAnimator can only be ran from the UI thread**